# nginx not showing internal at directory

Tags: nginx, security

Below is my nginx configuration file. It should make /inc and /admin/inc internal, but I can access them normally, like the line doesn't even exist. It's not giving me a 404 for external requests like it should. I've tried throwing in a deny all; instead just to test that it's matching, but even the deny all didn't work out. I've tried #nginx and a few sysadmin friends and I was referred to here.

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                rewrite ^/((?i)sitemap-([^./]+)\.xml)$ /misc.php?google_seo_sitemap=$2;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri&$args;
                index index.php;
        }

        location /inc {
                internal;
        }


        location /admin {
                include inc/adminip;

                        location /inc {
                                internal;
                        }

                        location ~ \.php$ {
                                include inc/php;
                        }
        }

        error_page 404 /index.php;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires 7d;
                access_log off;
                add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include inc/php;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show any url, but I'm pretty sure it ends with `.php`.

Everyone really should read [how nginx chooses location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration).

In short, locations are exclusive and in general nginx prefer regexp locations to prefixed ones. To prevent this you have to use flag `^~` in location:

```
location ^~ /inc {
    internal;
}
```

With this block, any url started with `/inc` will be denied. But there is caveat, even url like `/increment` or `/income` will be denied, which is not what you usually wants, so it's better to use trailing slash:

```
location ^~ /inc/ {
    internal;
}
```

and your second internal block should be

```
location ^~ /admin/inc/ {
    internal;
}
```

BTW, your nested php location inside `admin` does nothing, because url `/admin/whatever.php` is served by last location block.